# Sum items with certain IDs in IEnumerable of a Custom Class

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, ienumerable

```
CustomClass{
int ID;
int numberToSum;
float numToAverage;
}


IEnumerable<CustomClass> results = MethodToPopulateIEnumerable();
List<int> listOfIDs = MethodToGetListOfIDs();
```

What I wish to do with these, is take my `IEnumberable<CustomClass>` and select all the ones where the ID is in the `List<int> listOfIDs`, then I wish to sum the `numberToSum` value of this and save it in a variable and get the average of the `numToAverage` property and save it in a variable.

What is the most elegant way to do this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
IEnumerable<CustomClass> results = MethodToPopulateIEnumerable();
List<int> listOfIDs = MethodToGetListOfIDs();
```

**Query Syntax**

```
 var query = from c in results
             where listOfIds.Any(x => x == c.ID)
             select c;
```

**Method Syntax**

```
var query = results.Where(c => listOfIds.Any(x => x == c.ID));
```

**Calculations**

```
int numberToSum = query.Sum(x => x.numberToSum);
float numToAverage = query.Average(x => x.numToAverage);
```

Another alternate method which would allievate some of the performances concerns by fellow members, but still allowing the query to be linq-to-whatever friendly (`linq-to-entities`, `linq-to-sql`):

```
var calculations = (from c in results
                   where listOfIds.Any(x => x == c.ID)
                   group c by 1 into g
                   select new {
                     numberToSum = g.Sum(x => x.numberToSum ),
                     numToAverage = g.Average(x => x.numToAverage),                
                   }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Perhaps if `listOfIDs` or `results` are sufficiently large enough, consider leveraging using a `HashMap` of IDs instead otherwise that could be _a lot_ of unnecessary/slow iteration. But otherwise if they're pretty small, that'll do the job nicely.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair You mean `HashSet` I assume.

Comment: @Servy Oops, yeah. I was thinking when I wrote it down that it didn't seem right. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's something like this:

```
var matchingIdsList = results.Where(x => listsOfIDs.Any(y => y == x.Id));
var sum = matchingIdsList.Sum(x=> x.numberToSum);
var average = matchingIdsList.Average(x=> x.numToAverage);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this as follows - not very elegant but more efficient:

```
// Load IDs into a hashset so Contains is O(1) not O(n)
var hashSetOfIDs = new HashSet<int>(listOfIDs);

// Aggreagate count and both sums in one pass, then calculate average.
var result = results.Where(cc => hashSetOfIDs.Contains(cc.ID)).Aggregate(
    new { Count = 0, Sum = 0, AverageSum = 0f },
    (a, cc) => new {
        Count = a.Count + 1,
        Sum = a.Sum + cc.numberToSum,
        AverageSum = a.AverageSum + cc.numToAverage },
    a => new { 
        Sum = a.Sum,
        Average = a.Count > 0 ? a.AverageSum / a.Count : float.NaN });

// Extract results
var sum = result.Sum;
var average = result.Average;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = MethodToPopulateIEnumerable();
var listOfIDs = MethodToGetListOfIDs();

int numberToSum = 0;
float numberToAverage = 0;

var selected = results.Where(c => listOfIDs.Contains(c.ID)).Select(c =>
  {
    numberToSum += c.numberToSum;
    numberToAverage += c.numToAverage;
    return c;
  }).ToList();

float average = numberToAverage/selected.Count;
```